# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2.2, spring-webflow-2

I don´t understand why this official example does not work.

I think someone will help me to solve this out.

Thanks in advance.

**The error message:**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Servlet] in context with path [/primefaces-showcase] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'view' of flow 'file-upload'] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
```

I tried configuring my files:

Web.xml (**input the config**)

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>C:\</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And also **input in servlet-context.xml**

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"> 
       <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Spring MVC != Spring Webflow. JSF/PrimeFaces does (afaik) not work with Spring MVC

Comment: Could you provide a link to the official example?

Comment: Did you seriously find an "official example" which maps file upload filter and `*.xhtml` to Spring MVC dispatcher servlet? I will contact the author.

Comment: GitGub: [link]https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples

Comment: BalusC, it was just a desperate attempt.